# Morse-Sard lemma

Tags: measure-theory, induction, proof-explanation, geometric-measure-theory

I would like to know what is the inductive hypothesis in the proof of the lemma below, which is quoted in the last line of the proof. I didn't understand this last line because I couldn't identify what is the inductive hypothesis in the beginning of the step $2$.

[image]

Comment: This proof is by induction on the dimension $n$ of the domain.  I believe the author is taking the result for granted when $n=1$. Perhaps this case was handled earlier.

Comment: Yes, but is the inductive hypothesis $|u(E_h)| = 0$ for $h = 1,\cdots,n-1$?

Comment: No, the inductive hypothesis is the entire statement of the theorem is true when $n$ is replaced by $n-1$.